# PHP fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found

Tags: php, json, jsonserializer

I have moved and configured my D8 site from Windows to Ubuntu 14.04 PC today. But when I run the site I am getting the following error:

> **Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in /var/www/eCartZone/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Render/MarkupInterface.php on line 32**

I checked for installed modules with `php -m` from the terminal and I found it in the list.

[image]

I installed Php 5.5.33 using `$ phpbrew install php-5.5.33 +default+json+mysql+curl`

**Version information:**

```
Php: 5.5.33
Drupal: 8.2.3
Apache: 2.4.7
MySql: 14.14, Distrib 5.5.53
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue! Somebody please help me with the solution.

**UPDATE**
Command output of `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep json`

```
PHP Warning:  phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Command line code on line 1
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--cache-file='''/home/subrara/.phpbrew/cache/config.cache'''' '--prefix=/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.33' '--with-config-file-path=/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.33/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.33/var/db' '--disable-all' '--enable-session' '--enable-short-tags' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--with-curl=/usr' '--enable-json' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-xml' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-xsl' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-cli' '--enable-ctype' '--enable-dom' '--enable-fileinfo' '--enable-filter' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mhash=/usr' '--with-mcrypt=/usr' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-pcre-dir=/usr' '--enable-pdo' '--enable-phar' '--enable-posix' '--with-readline=/usr' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-tokenizer' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--enable-zip' '--with-pear=/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.33/lib/php' '--enable-zend-signals'
/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.33/var/db/json.ini
json
json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1
```

Comment: What shows `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep json` ?

Comment: Also the loaded modules are different depending on whether you're using built-in php or a web server like apache.

Comment: Are you running the same PHP version in your browser as you are in the console?

Comment: I have updated my question with the output of `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep json` command. Both browser and CLI tool show same PHP version, i.e. 5.5.33. @JezEmery if you don't mind would you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @SubrataSarkar if you type `php -m` on the command line, and run `phpinfo();` from within a browser, it is possible to have entirely different modules installed as it's possible to have separate `php.ini` files for each installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install php-json on your system. On redhat-based OSes you could install it with:

```
sudo dnf install php-json
```

On Debian-based OSes, do:

```
sudo apt-get install php-json
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I finally got the solution! Hope this might help others as well.

**Drupal 8 is said to work on PHP 5.5.9+, while my php version was 5.5.33.**

I updated my PHP to 5.6.22 and the error is gone!

```
$ phpbrew install php-5.6.22 +default+curl+json+mysql+apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
$ phpbrew switch php-5.6.22
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Both my browser (`phpinfo();`) and CLI now showing 5.6.22 as the active version!

Thanks to [jimsmith](https://drupaltwig.slack.com/team/jimsmith) :)

Comment: Maybe you should use php7.