# PHP Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found when i upload it to cpanel

Tags: laravel, server, cpanel

PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in /home/peoplesi/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line 40

i get this error when i upload it to cpanel

My php version is 7
i also tried composer update many time

Can anyone kindly give me a solution to remove this error

Comment: What is your Laravel version ?

Comment: laravel version is 8

Comment: I think this is not laravel related problem, please update your php ver to 7.2 if possible and also check JSON extension is enable there or not.This question is asked multiple time over community please check those links as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022852/php-fatal-error-interface-jsonserializable-not-found

Comment: updated my php to 7.2 and json also enabled . My project run perfectly on my localhost but get the error when upload to cpanel .

Comment: i checked the answer from comumnity but did not get the solution

Comment: Basically this error was generated when JSON is not supported on server. I also read many blogs regarding this error they all have same solution, I recommend you to please check once with your server support  for cross checking JSON is enable on you server or not. and also please try once with php 7.3.

Comment: ok i will try that as well